# Moving character relative to their location using rigidbody unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 3d

As shown in the video link below, the player is moving relative to the global axis, therefore it's having some annoying effects.

I want to make it so the character moves on its local axis, that way it will be easier to apply animations for when he's walking backwards, sideways, etc. How can I do this?

Here's the link to the video of what's happening:
[Link](https://youtu.be/MItPkA-OHb4)

Also, here is the code for my Character Movement script:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float speed = 6f;            // The speed that the player will move at.
    Vector3 movement;                   // The vector to store the direction of the player's movement.
    Animator anim;                      // Reference to the animator component.
    Rigidbody playerRigidbody;          // Reference to the player's rigidbody.
    int floorMask;                      // A layer mask so that a ray can be cast just at gameobjects on the floor layer.
    float camRayLength = 100f;          // The length of the ray from the camera into the scene.

void Awake ()
{
    // Create a layer mask for the floor layer.
    floorMask = LayerMask.GetMask ("Floor");

    // Set up references.
    anim = GetComponent <Animator> ();
    playerRigidbody = GetComponent <Rigidbody> ();
}


void FixedUpdate ()
{
    // Store the input axes.
    float h = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");
    float v = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Vertical");

    // Move the player around the scene.
    Move (h, v);

    // Turn the player to face the mouse cursor.
    Turning ();

    // Animate the player.
    Animating (h, v);
}

void Move (float h, float v)
{
    // Set the movement vector based on the axis input.
    movement.Set (h, 0f, v);

    // Normalise the movement vector and make it proportional to the speed per second.
    movement = movement.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Move the player to it's current position plus the movement.
    playerRigidbody.MovePosition (transform.position + movement);
}
```

Let me know if you need anything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever you use the Transform members: position, rotation, and lossyScale, you are working with world-space.

If you wish to use local-space/model-space:  you should instead use localPosition, localRotation, and localScale.

Unfortunately rigidbody does NOT have a Move**Local**Position function.
Instead, try this line to manually update the position:

```
transform.localPosition+=movement;
```